# How to trigger initial login so user slice gets created

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, containers, cgroup

I may be taking the wrong approach here, but the new centos 7 implementation of cgroups lets you put limits on user's access to system resources by attaching said limits to their slices.

Ie.

`systemctl set-property user-1005.slice CPUShares=100`

However, that slice won't exist until the user has initially logged in.  Since I'll be creating the user, I would kind of like to just trigger that initial log in at creation time, and then attach some default cgroup values then.  I tried just using `su` but that didn't work.  The only other thing I can think of is to actually set a password on the user and ssh in locally, which seems like a headache.  Is there a simple tool for initiating a log in that might create a user's slice?  Or even a better approach to this problem?

Cheers!

Comment: Why do you need the slice created before the user ever logs in?

Comment: @MichaelHampton so the cgroups are readily applied on any action they take upon initial login.